# Indexing a java 17 project using sourcegraph's scip-java

Tags: java-17

I am following the method given at:
https://sourcegraph.github.io/scip-java/docs/getting-started.html

From the root directory of a project I am running :
docker run -v $(pwd):/home/gradle sourcegraph/scip-java:latest scip-java index --build-tool=gradle

But on running this command I am getting the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sourcegraph.semanticdb_javac.SemanticdbPlugin (in unnamed module @0x1794d431) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.api to unnamed module @0x1794d431
```

In the getting started guide it says that Java 17 requires custom --add-exports (https://sourcegraph.github.io/scip-java/docs/getting-started.html#java)

For Java 17 and newer versions, the following JVM options are required:

```
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I have tried various ways to add these options but have not been able to do it correctly
(Following are some things I tried and the corresponding error I got)

```
docker run -e JAVA_OPTS="--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED" -v $(pwd):/home/gradle sourcegraph/scip-java:latest scip-java index --build-tool=gradle
```

Using JVM version 'temurin:17'
Unrecognized option: --add-exports
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --add-exports
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

```
docker run -e JAVA_OPTS="jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED" -v $(pwd):/home/gradle sourcegraph/scip-java:latest scip-java index --build-tool=gradle
```

Using JVM version 'temurin:17'
Error: Could not find or load main class jdk.compiler.com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not find or load main class jdk.compiler.com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED

I don't have very basic experience with Java programming, and currently, my main objective is to index a repository and test the Sourcegraph precise code intelligence tool.
(I am trying to index: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework)

How can I add these JVM options?

Edit:

I tried using Holdger's way(from the comments) but still getting the same errors.

```
docker run -e JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED" -v $(pwd):/home/gradle sourcegraph/scip-java:latest scip-java index --build-tool=gradle
```

The error message I got was(It is just the part where the task fails):

NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sourcegraph.semanticdb_javac.SemanticdbPlugin (in unnamed module @0x1794d431) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.api to unnamed module @0x1794d431
at com.sourcegraph.semanticdb_javac.SemanticdbPlugin.init(SemanticdbPlugin.java:19)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask.initPlugin(BasicJavacTask.java:255)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask.initPlugins(BasicJavacTask.java:229)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:292)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:176)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:64)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:50)

Comment: That may depend on how this `JAVA_OPTS` comes into life. According to the documentation, the standard Java launcher doesn’t support such a variable. Instead, [there is `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#using-the-jdk_java_options-launcher-environment-variable) and when I set it to `--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED`, it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am still getting errors. I tried JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS but still got the same error just with an extra line(edited the question with the exact command used and error message). And that JAVA_OPTS thing I actually tried by looking at some other stack overflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153917/how-to-set-jvm-settings-in-dockerfile)

Comment: Ok. The “Picked up…” message clearly indicates that the option has been processed and there’s no follow-up error about an invalid option, so we have to assume that the option is active. Since this contradicts the fact that there’s still the IllegalAccessError, I make an educated guess: it’s a different JVM, i.e. javac has been started as a subprocess.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delay. Here is what I was told: "Should be handled by this PR once it's merged https://github.com/sourcegraph/scip-java/pull/464"

Answer (score 1):

I left a comment but didn't get a response. Hopefully, this works.

This should be fixed with this PR: https://github.com/sourcegraph/scip-java/pull/464

Try re-running

```
$ docker run -v $(pwd):/home/gradle sourcegraph/scip-java:latest scip-java index --build-tool=gradle
```